# How to have 2 headers (row & column)

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-formula

I want to create a table where there are 2 axis. It seems I can only create a table where the first row is a header/axis.

My table looks something like this:

|  | 1/1/21 | 2/1/21 | 3/1/21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 AM | Work | Work | Work |
| 11:00:00 AM | Relaxing | Work | Watching TV |
| 12:00:00 AM | Work | Relaxing | Watching TV |
| 13:00:00 AM | Lunch | Lunch | Work |

As you can see the time and the date are axis. This way I can create a column graph and see how many hours I spent doing one thing each day. And I can also create another chart and see what thing I do the most during each hour. How am I able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Records have one "axis" only: Fields.

So, combine date and time into one field, have another field for work type, and then use a *crosstab query* filtering on a period of dates and grouping on *time* of the date/time values.